# Difference in free space available in a directory after mounting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have mounted a roughly 340 GB partition (of an SSD) at `/`. I then mounted another 600 GB partition (of an HDD) at `/home/Hard_disk_space`.

My disk analyzer output looks like this:
[image]

When I right-click 'Properties' on my home folder, I get the following, which makes sense:
[image]

However, when I right click 'Properties' on the folder 'Hard_disk_space', I get this:
[image]

Why does the 'Properties' output show only 315 GB? Do I have 600 GB in this folder? And does any file I store in this folder get written to the hard disk, or does it get written on the SSD because of its parent folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're viewing the properties of a directory `/home/tinkidinki/Hard_disk_space`, but the disk is mounted to `/home/Hard_disk_space`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are seeing the properties of /home folder only.

click on other locations/ devices and select individual disk/ partition. There you can see the properties / ree disk space of that volume/ disk.